How to type hint `cond->` within `->`
The following code produces two reflection warnings (for .getBytes):
(defn make-it-a-string-please [x]
  (str x))

(defn test1 [x]
  (-> x
      (cond-> (int? x) make-it-a-string-please)
      (.getBytes)))

(defn test2 [x]
  (-> x
      (make-it-a-string-please)
      (.getBytes)))

I can type hint test2:
(defn test2 [x]
  (-> x
      ^String (make-it-a-string-please)
      (.getBytes)))

Now the reflection warning is gone. But a similar type hint in test1 doesn't work:
(defn test1 [x]
  (-> x
      ^String (cond-> (int? x) make-it-a-string-please)
      (.getBytes)))

Is it possible to type hint this without modifying make-it-a-string-please and without extracting the cond-> part to a var (to type hint it there)?

FWIW, in Clojure 1.12 it's possible to avoid type hints here altogether if you use String/.getBytes instead of .getBytes.

@EugenePakhomov Good point, yeah. I'm on Clojure 1.11 now though.

You should consider both branches of the cond expression.

When (int? x) is true, the result of (make-it-a-string-please x) will be called, which can be type hinted directly on the function definition:

(defn make-it-a-string-please ^String [x]
  (str x))


Else, the value of x will be used, but we have no information about its type either. You can type hint it as well.

(defn test1 [x]
  (-> ^String x
      (cond-> (int? x) make-it-a-string-please)
      (.getBytes)))

(Please note, type hinting does not enforce the type, it only helps the compiler to prevent reflection calls.)

Alternatively, you can just add a redundant toString convertion (which does nothing because x is already a String) before the .getBytes call:
(defn test1 [x]
  (-> x
      (cond-> (int? x) make-it-a-string-please)
      (str)
      (.getBytes)))


I'm aware of having to type hint both branches - and I was expecting to type hint both branches by putting ^String left of (cond-> ....  The idea of using (str) is pretty nice though. Perhaps not super elegant, but does the job without having to refactor this code.

As a slight improvement, I'd change (-> x (cond-> ...) (str) (.getBytes)) to (-> x (cond-> ...) ^String (identity) (.getBytes)). Just to be extra clear why this (otherwise) unnecessary operation is there.
